# Correct pattern for using <Query> in other class methods

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I understand Apollo prefers we use `<Query>` in our render methods to do queries, rather than `this.props.client.query()`.

Every new class I create, I begin with the `<Query>` component (to stay best-practice), but 100% percent of the time end up removing it and just doing `this.props.client.query()` in my `componentWillMount`, otherwise basically every other class method is useless, as it can't access any of the data it needs.

Is it deliberate that anything obtained from a `<Query>` component is only useable in `render()`?

Is relying pretty much solely on `this.props.client.query()` is anti-pattern? If so, am I expected to create *another* component to put inside my `<Query>` so that things like `componentDidUpdate` aren't rendered useless?

Apologies for all the questions, I'm fairly surprised I haven't seen this question asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason *not* to use `client.query` is that it does not observe your cache for changes. If the information is updated in the cache (for example, following a mutation), the data rendered in your component will not be updated unless it's re-mounted.

If you have a class component, and you're using the `Query` component and you need the provided data available to methods outside of `render`, then yes, you need to have two components so that the data can be passed down as a prop. This effectively forces you to use the [container/presenter pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Or you can just use the `graphql` HOC to the same effect.

However... as of version 3.0, both the render-prop components and the HOC are all [deprecated](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/api/react-components/). So in terms of "best practices", you probably want to [migrate](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v3.0-beta/migrating/hooks-migration/) to using functional components and hooks anyway.

Comment: Fantastic answer, Daniel. Thank you so much for that.